# Postgres ignoring index using the COALESCE function

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the following table, with ~4 million rows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE members (
  id                INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  created_at        TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  updated_at        TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  -- other columns...
);
```

I use this following query to extract the latest updated rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM members
WHERE COALESCE(updated_at, created_at) > current_timestamp - interval '24 hours'
```

This query is obviously slow, so I created an index, but it is not used by Postgres:

```sql
CREATE INDEX members_updated_or_created_at ON members(COALESCE(updated_at, created_at));
```

Here's the execution plan:

```
Seq Scan on members  (cost=0.00..171792.01 rows=1326991 width=1826) (actual time=62.663..22064.805 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (COALESCE(updated_at, created_at) > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '48:00:00'::interval))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 3980971
Planning Time: 0.123 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 2
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 7.481 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 8.067 ms, Emission 35.308 ms, Total 50.857 ms
Execution Time: 22072.906 ms
```

I don't understand why it's doing a table scan instead of using an index scan. I also tried to select fewer fields, and adding a limit, but it didn't change anything.

**EDIT:**

So it seems like the index is not used because I'm fetching many columns that are not present in the index (select *).

I tried to do the same with the `updated_at` column, and this time, the index is used if the only column I select is the "updated_at" column (Index Only Scan), it is not used if I include another column though.

What I don't understand, is why don't I get the same behavior with the coalesce function?

**This query results in a full table scan**

```
SELECT coalesce(updated_at, created_at)
FROM members
WHERE coalesce(updated_at, created_at) > current_timestamp - interval '7 days';
```

**This query results in an Index Only Scan (index on updated_at)**

```
SELECT updated_at
FROM members
WHERE updated_at > current_timestamp - interval '7 days';
```

Comment: What if you create indexes for each column, and also for the tuple (without function call)?

Comment: Because your predicate is not sargable and you are selecting all columns; Try with an index on each column and two separate unioned queries - it will still depend in whether your indexes are covering or not.

Comment: Did you ANALYZE the table after creating the index?

Comment: Trying to index on COALESCE makes no sense. How would the index know which of the two values is being returned by the function in order to index it?

Comment: @KenWhite  Same way coalesce know how to do that when it isn't in an index.   The function doesn't know it is in an index, it just spits out a result and that result gets indexed.

Comment: @jjanes: When a query executes, the COALESCE function is called for each row to determine which of the columns should be returned. An index is built statically to speed access to the data. The only way that COALESCE would be called is when the index is created, and would have no way to know when a non-indexed column (either of the ones in the COALESCE call) was updated unless the index was rebuilt.

Comment: @KenWhite The system knows which columns the functional index has a dependency on, and so knows when to do maintenance.

Comment: @KenWhite: however that index does store the result of the coalesce() call, so in theory this should be usable.

Comment: Yes, I used `ANALYZE` to get the execution plan. The index is used when I use the equality operator, but not when I use a range operator

Comment: Indexes on the two columns are not used either - from what I understood, the db should use the first index I created (the one with COALESCE), but it does not, probably because it thinks it'll have to scan a big range in the index and so it prefers to scan the whole table directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in order to force the DB to use my index, I added an "ORDER BY" clause, and it seems to work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM members
WHERE coalesce(updated_at, created_at) > current_timestamp - interval '7 days'
ORDER BY coalesce(updated_at, created_at) DESC;
```

```
Index Scan Backward using members_updated_or_created_at on members  (cost=0.43..446282.78 rows=1326991 width=1834) (actual time=8.367..8.369 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (COALESCE(updated_at, created_at) > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '7 days'::interval))
Planning Time: 0.261 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 5
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.065 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.825 ms, Emission 7.484 ms, Total 10.375 ms
Execution Time: 10.524 ms
```